# What did the Bishop mean by his "last remittance"?

Tags: dialogue, v-for-vendetta

In the scene with Bishop Lilliman from *V for Vendetta*, the Bishop says to his assistant:

> It wasn't labor that I was speaking of, but rather my final remittance. My last little joy.

Right before the scene with Evey dressed as a schoolgirl. Yet, why was he speaking of his next lewd act as his final? Did I miss something, or was something cut from the script?

I know we, the viewers, are aware it's about to be his last *anything*, but why did the Bishop use this phrase? Is it related to why V's plans "accelerated"?

Comment: Does the bishop say this when he is with Evie?  Is that the scene that you're referring to?

Comment: @steelersquirrel Right before that. I mistyped and meant no say with his assistant

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstand: He doesn't mean that it will be "the last time he will do something fun" (and after that he will be living a joyless life)  but "the last thing that gives him joy", the "only little source of pleasure that he allows himself to have" (because he is so committed to his work).

More obvious example would be saying something like  "My dog is my last joy" or "Tom is my last high school friend"  - it doesn't mean that I'll see my dog for the last time after today or that Tom will die,  but that besides playing with my dog my life is joyless and that you don't have other friends (because i.e. you've lost contact with them) from high school than Tom.

Comment: Are there examples of speech like this somewhere? It's an interesting interpretation, and I'm wondering if it's "common"? British usage?

Comment: For example this lyrics - https://www.vagalume.com.br/fold-zandura/my-last-joy.html - the "last joy" is speaking his/her lover's name, it doesn't mean it's done for the last time.